# Anyone can suggest autocomplete search

Tags: php, search, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm a total newbie and I'm looking for a way to have a search box with autocomplete just like google does.

I've searched and the best prospect that I've found seems to be [this forum post](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm). The guy who suggested it says he uses it with [this project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/searchable-behaviour-for-cakephp/)  which is dead on because I've managed to install searchable on my last attempt at figuring out cakephp.

The thing is, I've not used much javascript before and I'm a bit confused as to what exactly I'm meant to be doing. The documentation with the autocomplete codes doesn't go into any detail that I can understand.

If we assume that I manage to get searchable behaviour installed correctly, could any kind person explain to me how I would go about making the autocomplete work?

It says to just use:

```
 $("selector").autocomplete(url [, options]);
```

eg:

```
 $("#input_box").autocomplete("autocomplete_ajax.cfm");
```

Autocomplete expects an input element with the id "input_box" to exist. When a user starts typing in the input box, the autocompleter will request autocomplete_ajax.cfm with a GET parameter named q

thats the bit I don't get. Where am I meant to put that? And once I've put it somewhere then do I just need to name one of my inputs "input_box"?

thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems you are not conversant with jQuery which would be a good place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

### Use this when you have predetermined set list of search options

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [ //array of searchable options
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
```

Source: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

## Method 2

### Use this when you are searching a database for autocomplete suggestions

jQuery code:

```
$('input#input_box').keypress(function(){ //letter has been pressed
    var search = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'autocomplete_ajax.php', //the php page that will handle the request
        type : 'GET', //the method of sending the data
        data: 'q='+search, //the data you are sending
        success : function(data){
            //the variable 'data' will be whatever the php outputs (via
            //any method - echo, exit, print, print_r etc. you can
            //use data from php page to output wherever you want, e.g.
            $('div#search_autosuggestbox').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="input_box" />
<div id="search_autosuggestbox"></div>
```

EDIT: added page names/values corresponding to the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting your source like so:

```
$("#input_box").autocomplete({source: "autocomplete_ajax.cfm"});
```